# How to change app theme using a promise with react native AsyncStorage?

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

i create 2 themes in my react native project and works good.

I just need to change lightMode to darkMode.

[image]
To use this theme i just need to import and use:
[image]

but now, i need to import lightMode dynamic, i can just use a switch:

[image]

but how i can do this, with asyncStorage? Because i need to work with promises:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please reopen this question, not is just a problem with promises, maybe i will need re-architect my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such situations,

You need to load all those data into memory from storage(AsyncStorage in this case) right after the app starts.

You can do this while you show the splash screen.

Comment: i understand, but if the user change the theme, he will need restart the app? :/

Comment: @JeanCatarina No. You can dynamically change the theme at runtime. https://www.seishin.me/dynamic-switching-of-themes-in-react-native-app/